# Use specific glyph name with no Unicode value in HTML?

Tags: html, character-encoding, glyph

How can I use for example the glyph name "rcaron.terminal" which has no Unicode value in HTML? or any other such case? Is it even possible? I think it must be surely but I got no clue. It's easy for regular letters like the glyph "ß" where I would just type "&#xDF" and get that character or "&#223" (same result) but for glyphs without any Unicode value I don't know what I'm supposed to do...? I've tried also "&rcaron.terminal" but nothing, where as something like "&hearts" would work giving a heart glyph of god knows what font, probably Arial I dunno.

Do I need to use state some specific encoding aside from ANSI in my html document?

ie. < meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-8" > or something... like Im really lost lol

All I found on the net was this http://text-symbols.com/html/unicode/ but I cant find any more info so I came here.

Please help! Thanks! :)

Comment: Apparently also crossposted to http://typophile.com/node/124066 ... This seems to be the only Google hit for "rcaron.terminal" other than this question.

Comment: I tried @ font-feature-values MyFontName { @styleset { aalt0: 1;  } }
p {  font-variant-alternates: styleset(aalt0);  } but doesnt work and its only possible in Firefox, how else can I do this? This info is from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant-alternates

Comment: That's a solution to a different problem.  I added a link to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are no glyphs in HTML which do not have a Unicode name.

If you really need to have a glyph which is not representable using regular Unicode, you might want to create a font of your own and define the glyphs you need in the private use area; but obviously, then, your HTML will be impossible to use without that particular font.

Background links:

- http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2008/10/embedded-web-fonts/
- http://www.font-face.com/

Practical guides:

- http://blog.fogcreek.com/trello-uses-an-icon-font-and-so-can-you/
- http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/07/how-to-make-an-icon-font-the-8-step-guide/

Answer (score 0):

1. First navigate to this site: https://fontdrop.info/#/?darkmode=true
2. Upload the file with your font
3. Click on the Ligatures tab.
4. Every Glyph should have a Components field
5. copy the components for the character you want to use
6. paste that string into HTML

You don't need any & or #, it just detects the string and converts it.